# Cannot scp to remote system

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, scp

I try to copy files from my raspberry pi. I can rsh from my host into the pi and list the files but I cannot scp. When I issue:

```
scp -r /home/arnold/pi arnold@192.168.158.147:/home/arnold
```

I get the error message:

```
setterm: $TERM is not defined.
```

TERM is set both on the host as on the raspberry. I googled for the error but in connection with scp I could not find any useful reference. I am somewhat baffled that scp needs TERM. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you entering `rcp` or `scp`? Your command above has `rcp`. I assume it's just a typo in your post and not what you entered when trying to scp, but just clarifying.

Comment: TERM is a variable which sets how output is displayed. Type the command TERM=vt100 (enter) and the them for your copying.

Comment: It is scp, sorry for the confusion. I set TERM=vt100, even exported it, but still the same error. I did a setterm vt100, that was ok, but still the same error.